# Optimum of coordinate-wise convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is convex in each coordinate:

$$
\forall i \in \{1, \dots, n\}. \forall x_1. \dots \forall x_{i-1}, \forall x_{i+1}\dots \forall x_n. f(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},\cdot,x_{i+1},\dots, x_n) \text{ is convex}
$$

Can $f$ have a local optimum that is not also a global optimum?

---

I already know that $f$ is not necessarily convex (consider, [e.g.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211531/proof-that-a-coordinate-wise-convex-function-is-convex), $f(x,y)=x \cdot y$). Therefore, I suspect that in general, $f$ may have local optimas. However, I could not find a counterexample so far ($x \cdot y$ has no optimum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$
f(x,y)
=
x^2 \, y^2 + 20 \, x \, y + x^2 + y^2 + x
$$
has two local minimizers (near $(-3,3)$ and $(3,-3)$) with different function values. Only one of these minimizers is the global minimizer.

Comment: Is it possible to have 3 local minima? In particular, can we say that a coordinate wise convex function on $n$ coordinates can only have $n$ distinct minima? (Unless it is constant.)